# Use custom function in Controller when using resource in routes - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, routes

Been building a framework website using Laravel and working on the user system.

I am using the controller by a resource route:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Which works fine for all the normal create, index, store etc function in the controller.

For my registration form this is the opening:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.store', 'class'=>'small-form form-holder')) }}
```

Thinking how nice this is, I created a login function in my UserController and tried this for my login form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.login', 'class'=>'small-form form-holder')) }}
```

However this returns a route not defined error. Is this because of the resource route that I set? I know I could set a custom route which uses the controllers login method but I like this way of doing things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Resource will generate following route names by default

```
user.index
user.create
user.store
user.show
user.edit
user.update
user.destroy
```

more information [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

If you want to create another route you could do this way

```
Route::get('user/login', 'UserController@login');

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

note: you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource

for more information you can look at [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) in **Adding Additional Routes To Resource Controllers** session

Comment: the note in the answer is very important. tnx